# Vite Error "Access is denied", when I make Vue3 apps using vite

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vite

I tried to use vite to make vue3 apps.
but when I build vue3 apps, build error occurred and
no apps shown in browser.

my PC and node.js version

```
windows:10
"node":"v16.13.2"
"npm":"v8.1.2"
```

Basically I started make vue3 apps following [the guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#trying-vite-online)  and used CommandPrompt to make apps like below.

```
$npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template vue
↓
$cd my-vue-app
↓
$npm install
↓
$npm run dev
```

and package.json like this.

```
{
  "name": "vue3testapps",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.0",
    "vite": "^2.6.14"
  }
}
```

after I command "npm run dev",
"Access is denied" was occurred in CommandPrompt.
[image]

I thought node.js and npm is ok because my other project
which is vue verison 2 is no problem and [githun issues](https://github.com/nuxt/vite/issues/207)
arguing about node version, but my version is seems ok.
How can I fix the build problem?
Does anyone help me, please?